# Attempting to Change Template logs out user

Tags: content-editor, security, content-management, role-management

On a site that was recently upgraded from v8.0 Update 3 to v8.1 Update 3, editors are reporting that when they attempt to change the template of an item, they end up on the login page. These users are all members of the  `sitecore\Sitecore Client Maintaining` group and should have access to this functionality. When they click the button in the ribbon, the following appears in the logs:

```
WARN  Request is redirected to login page. Requested url: /sitecore/shell/Applications/Templates/Change template.aspx?id=%7B05F2603F-DF10-42E8-B9E2-4A25DECFDFF1%7D, User: sitecore\editorUserId, Website: shell
```

There have been several other cases where the security settings in core have impacted the editors, but I can't find what is causing this one.

Comment: Does this only impact the editors? Or do admins see the same problem? It does seem like the page is doing a security challenge and the current user isn't passing it.

Comment: Admins don't see it. This is built-in functionality that should be available to the Sitecore Client Maintaining role.

Comment: I had this exact same issue a few years ago. Sorry I can’t remember the fix. But it was an item/application in core that needed permissions set on it. I contacted support.